# In OIDC, what is the difference between an Authorization Code and an Authorization Token?

Tags: openid-connect

The title says it all.  I'm really confused with terminology, and since I have to implement this, I can't afford even a slight confusion.  If they are the same thing--fine; I just want perfect clarity.

And for search engines:  OIDC = OpenId Connect.

Answer (score 1):

An authorization code is a part of the mechanics for handling OIDC browser redirects securely. It ensures that access tokens are never available in the browser history.

An access token is a message credential sent to OAuth secured APIs in the Authorization header.

To visualise usage, have a look at my [Initial OAuth Messages](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow) blog post. Once people understand messages used in OAuth flows they are much more productive.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Gary Archer for your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65979360/624814).  My answer is in conjunction with yours.

The **authorization code** (during the OAuth2.0 dance) is the data returned by the browser to the client application. The client sends this code to an *authorization server* to get an **access token**.  The client uses this **access token** to get the desired data from the *resource server*.

Please comment if I'm missing something!